# How to trigger auto layout after I change the size of one subview?

Tags: ios, autolayout

I am making a view controller with a search bar on top and a table view filling the rest part of the view.

[image]

Now I need the visibility of the search bar to be configurable. What I am doing is like this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
    if (!(self.bShowSearchBar)) {
        [self.searchBar setHidden:YES];
        CGRect frameSearchBar = self.searchBar.frame;
        frameSearchBar.size.height = 0;
        [self.searchBar setFrame:frameSearchBar];
        NSLog(@"self.searchBar.frame: %@", NSStringFromCGRect(self.searchBar.frame));
        NSLog(@"self.tableView.frame: %@", NSStringFromCGRect(self.tableView.frame));
    }
}
```

The table view's position is not correctly adjusted when I hide the search bar. The NSLog shows the frame of search bar is already changed while the frame of table view refuse to be adjusted:

```
2017-03-27 15:37:41.204413 App[2071:954793] self.searchBar.frame: {{0, 0}, {375, 0}}
2017-03-27 15:37:41.204675 App[2071:954793] self.tableView.frame: {{0, 44}, {375, 623}}
```

but it just does not show up correctly. The place for the search bar is still held.

[image]

I also tried with

```
 (1) [self.tableView setNeedsLayout];
     [self.tableView layoutIfNeeded];

 (2) [self.view layoutSubviews];
```

right after I set the search bar height to 0, but none of them works.

So how can I re-trigger the auto layout after I modified the size of one subview? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't change the frame if you are using autolayout. Change the constraint

Answer (score 2):

You can't change a view's frame in Autolayout.It doesn't work if you open Autolayout option.You should change the constraint instead.

From your picture,
[image]

press on control and drag this constraint to your .m file,to make it as a property.

When you want to make some change,just change this property.

Refer to your case,in `viewDidLoad`,you could set the top of the search bar equals -44,since the search bar's height equals 44,then -44 means 44point above the screen.By this change,the tableview will also change its frame because its top constraint to the search bar'bottom equals 0.Now you'v hidden your search bar and make the tableview's frame right.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Henson, and for other's convenience, the solution turns to be this:

(1) Remove "Search Bar.top = top" from Interface Builder;

(2) In viewDidLoad,

```
if (self.bShowSearchBar) {
    [self.searchBar setHidden:NO];
    NSLayoutConstraint *topConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.searchBar attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop multiplier:1.0 constant:0.0];
    [self.view addConstraint:topConstraint];
}
else {
    [self.searchBar setHidden:YES];
    NSLayoutConstraint *topConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.searchBar attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop multiplier:1.0 constant:-44.0];
    [self.view addConstraint:topConstraint];
}
[self.view updateConstraints];
```

It is working perfectly!